# no `HashMap` in `collections` in Substrate

Tags: data-type

I can not use **HashMap** in scale_info packages, but when I search in Substrate docs https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/latest/scale_info/prelude/collections/struct.HashMap.html. we can use **HashMap**

My current scale_info package:

```
scale-info = { version = "2.0.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
```

When i **cargo build --release** -> **no `HashMap` in `collections`**

Is it eliminated?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at this time, the `latest` tag on the rustdocs is not pointing to a recent version of substrate source upstream. Please use `master`:

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/scale_info/prelude/collections/struct.HashMap.html

And if in doubt, the source on github master branch is best to reference as the source of truth.

The scale-info crate now lives in a separate repository, and is at this time using [version 2.1.2](https://github.com/paritytech/scale-info/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L3). I see no HashMap implementation.

You should very likely not be using the crates.io versions of Substrate and SCALE info. Instead, it is best now to use the most recent release of Polkadot tagged versions of things in your projects, like the devhub node template `latest` tag uses:
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/latest

All docs.substrate.io examples use this as a reference.